# I guesstimated my taxes and overpaid a bit before April 15. But I have not filed. Where can I file and not pay?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, turbotax, estimated-taxes, electronic-filing

I am filing late so I guesstimated my tax bill and overpaid it directly on irs.gov (to prevent penalties. So I have paid a bit too much, but have not filed.

Where (Turbotax?) can I file but not pay?

Follow-up. It is likely that I overpaid for 2021. If I file before the late filing deadline (which I have already applied, and paid, for) then do I simply deduct this from my 2022 taxes?

Comment: Did you pay it as "extension payment" or "balance due"? Did you make sure it was for 2021?

Comment: @user102008 Extension payment

Comment: I think Turbotax should have a place to enter extension payments paid. If filling the forms manually, it should be included in 1040 Schedule 3 line 10.

Answer (score 6):

On your 1040 line 26, you can report all past payments made for the year. [https://www.irs.gov/faqs/estimated-tax/individuals#:~:text=Report%20all%20your%20estimated%20tax,your%20prior%20year%20tax%20return](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/estimated-tax/individuals#:%7E:text=Report%20all%20your%20estimated%20tax,your%20prior%20year%20tax%20return).

When you include those payments in your return, your tax software will consider that as a reduction of taxes still outstanding, and if you have a refund owing to you from the IRS, it will be provided after they process your return.

Comment: If it's paid after January 15 of the following year, it's not an estimated tax payment, but an extension payment, and should be listed on 1040 Schedule 3 line 10.

Comment: @user102008 Thanks for the clarification. Is it correct to say that Sched 3 line 10 would only be appropriate if you actually filed the request for extension? I'm curious if the OP just sent in an extra payment without actually filing extension.

Comment: Making an extension payment automatically counts as a request for extension, without the need to file a separate form. Filing a separate form for extension is only needed if you don't need to make a payment.

Answer (score 3):

When filing your taxes, the estimated pre-payments are a part of the filing and will be respected - so you wouldn’t have to pay it again.
*Any* way to file your taxes you would normally use works. The amount due will simply come out lower by the amount you pre-payed (potentially being a refund now).